# How put every files result by a grep into a zip file

Tags: linux, grep, zip

I'm searching every txt files that contains string1 and string2

```
grep -rnE --include='*.txt' 'string1|string2'
```

Now I want to put all those files into a zip file.

Thanks

**EDIT**
this script suggest by @anubhava works for me

```
grep --null -rlE --include='*.txt' 'string1|string2' | xargs -0 -I {} zip test.zip '{}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `-l` option in `grep` to output only filename and pipe it to `xargs` to create `zip` for each found fine:

```sh
grep --null -rlE --include='*.txt' 'string1|string2' |
xargs -0 -I {} zip '{}'.zip '{}'
```

Note use of `--null` option with `-0` in `xargs` to address filenames with whitespaces, special characters.

---

To create a single zip file containing each matched file use:

```
grep --null -rlE --include='*.txt' 'string1|string2' |
xargs -0 zip test.zip
```

Comment: Thanks, this command create a zip file like mytextfile.txt.zip inside each folder where has been found 'string1|string2' into the files. I want a single zip create in a root folder (where I launch the command) that contains every files that match my grep. Thanks a lot

Comment: ok using this command works for me

grep --null -rlE --include='*.txt' 'string1|string2' | xargs -0 -I {} zip test.zip '{}'

Thanks

Comment: To create a single zip use `grep --null -rlE --include='*.txt' 'string1|string2' | xargs -0 zip test.zip` it will be more efficient

Answer (score 1):

since you wanted files that contain both string1 **and** string2

```
$ files=""; for i in *.txt; do if  grep -q string1 $i &&  grep -q string2 $i; then files="$files $i"; fi; done
$ zip files.zip ${files}
```

**cleaner version**

```
files=""; 
for i in *.txt; 
  do 
    if  grep -q string1 $i &&  grep -q string2 $i; then 
      files="$files $i"; 
    fi; 
  done
zip files.zip ${files}
```

**DEMO**:

```
$ cat SO/file1.txt
there is string1
there is also string2
$
$ cat SO/file2.txt
there is just string1
$
$ cat SO/file3.txt
here we have both string1 and string2
$
$
$ files="";
$ for i in SO/*.txt;
>   do
>     if  grep -q string1 $i &&  grep -q string2 $i; then
>       files="$files $i";
>     fi;
>   done
$ zip files.zip ${files}
  adding: SO/file1.txt (deflated 26%)
  adding: SO/file3.txt (deflated 11%)
$
```

Comment: Hi Vijayendar Gururaja, when I run this script I recevice this error

xxxxxxxx:~/testzipemail$ ./testgrep.sh
grep: *.txt: No such file or directory

zip error: Nothing to do! (files.zip)

Comment: Added a demo to answer. You need to ensure that the for loop has the path to your text files. In the demo I have my txt files under /SO/*.txt. You can update your required path instead. For portability, you can also convert this into a function to accept the path and comma separated strings as script arguments so that you can run it like ./script.sh /my/folder/path/*.txt string1,string2,stringX.

Comment: Thanks Vijayendar Gururaja for your answer but I think that a single line command is better then a bash script ;-)